Goals and Buddhism
How are goals used in Theravada Buddhism and Buddhist practice in general in a positive way.
How do goals relate to the early teachings, and one's own practice in a positive way.

Prior discussions on Buddhism Stack Exchange:

Difference between Attachment and Goals
Does suffering motivate us to achieve our goals?
Is it possible to set goals for the future and be present at the same time?
Is Nirvana the goal, for Zen and Theravada?
Why does Buddhism seem to have more than one goal?
Should meditation be practiced without a goal?
Is Nirvana the goal for all Buddhist?
Is mindfulness the path or the goal?
How can someone integrate the Buddhist philosophy on life's purpose into daily life?
Ambitions - Are they Real or just an Illusion
Stopping Tanha or craving
Attachment to practice itself


SN 56.7 Vitakkasutta – mjaviem translation

‘Bhikkhus, do not think/intend/aim/set for yourselves dismal thoughts/purposes/resolutions which do no good; that is, thoughts/purposes/resolutions of sensuality, thoughts/purposes/resolutions of malevolence, thoughts/purposes/resolutions of inhumanity. Why? These thoughts/purposes/resolutions, bhikkhus, are not pertinent, they are not directed to spiritual conduct, to jadedness, to disinterestedness, to clearing, to tranquillity, to realisation, to enlightenment, to dissipation.


‘When you think/intend/aim/set for yourselves at something, bhikkhus, you should think/intend/aim/set for yourselves at: ‘This is difficulty’; you should think/intend/aim/set for yourselves at: ‘This is the source of difficulty’; you should think/intend/aim/set for yourselves at: ‘This is the clearing of difficulty’; you should think/intend/aim/set for yourselves at: ‘This is the dedication that leads to the clearing of difficulty.’ Why? These purposes/resolutions, bhikkhus, are pertinent, they are directed to spiritual conduct, to jadedness, to disinterestedness, to clearing, to tranquillity, to realisation, to enlightenment, to dissipation.


‘Therefore, bhikkhus, one should devote oneself to: ‘This is difficulty’. One has to devote oneself to: ‘This is the source of difficulty.’ One has to devote oneself to: ‘This is the clearing of difficulty’. One must devote oneself to: ‘This is the dedication that leads to the clearing of difficulty’.’


Great ref. I think also there is a sutta (maybe MN) that uses goals as its framework for Nibbana.
